# Products filtered by specific product attribute value in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product, custom-taxonomy

I have a problem with woocommerce shortcodes. I have products on backend side but after upgrading woocommerce to latest version (3.3.5) I noticed that shortcodes are not same anymore. I used to query product by attribute with [product_attributes] shortcode. According to woocommerce docs this shortcode is turned on [products] with attributes.

This is my shortcode:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[products attribute="collezione_chakra" terms="stella" limit="-1"]'); ?>
```

[image]

As you can see stella attribute has 3 products and also the taxonomy is correct (I think), as you can see here below.

[image]

I've also tried using pa_ as taxonomy prefix as you can see below, but not working

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[products attribute="pa_collezione_chakra" terms="stella" limit="-1"]'); ?>
```

What is going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: But as you can see on my screenshot the slug is with the underscore... and an important information... If I do [products] with no parameters nothing happen

Comment: Anyway this kind of shordcode works (for woocommerce versions 3.2+)

Comment: Just for confirm if I echo [products] shortcode all the products should be listed right?

Comment: `echo do_shortcode( "[products limit='-1']" );` will do that.

Comment: It’s what I did before but what it echoes it’s an <ul></ul> empty element

Comment: The shortcode works. Maybe the problem is where you add it. Try to add only the shortcode (just for testing) in the content Wordpress editor of any page.

Comment: Ok I will try. I added it in a template php file... as per other shortcodes...